# Array urls - echo next url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

**PHP**

```
$urls = Array('www.1.com.br','www.2.com.br', 'www.3.com.br');
```

**HTML**

```
<iframe src="www.1.com.br" width='100%' height='100%'></iframe>

<button>Next</button>
```

How do I click the next button only update the iframe url (not update full page) in the sequence of URLs array?

I am in doubt also whether it is better an array with all urls in php or javascript

**UPDATE**

```
<script>
    jQuery('#someFrame').submit(function(){             
           $.ajax({
            url: 'updateUrl.php',
            type: '???',
            data: ????,
        });     
    })



var currentIndex = 0;
var urls = ['www.1.com.br','www.2.com.br', 'www.3.com.br'];
document.getElementById('someButton').addEventListener('click', function () {
    currentIndex = Math.min(currentIndex + 1, urls.length - 1);
    document.getElementById('someFrame').setAttribute('src', urls[currentIndex]);
});
</script>

<iframe src="www.1.com.br" width='100%' height='100%' id="someFrame"></iframe>
<button id="someButton">Next</button>
```

What need to have the page updateUrl.php, to refresh the page without refresh?

Comment: you need to use ajax for that

Comment: using javascript for this will make your work a lot easier. store the urls into a js array and then you can work with it.

Comment: Can you explain the changes you made under "Update" on your question? I'm not sure what you're asking

Comment: Your code works fine for me, but every click on the button next to full page update, I need only update the iframe

Answer (score 2):

This can't be done purely with PHP, you'll need JS to get it to work. PHP is interpreted by the webserver, so by the time it hits the browser, the browser has no knowledge of that PHP. So it can't really be interactive in the sense that you want it to be.

JavaScript, on the other hand, is perfect for this kind of interaction-without-refresh behaviour.

So something like

HTML

```
<iframe src="www.1.com.br" width='100%' height='100%' id="someFrame"></iframe>
<button id="someButton">Next</button>
```

Javascript

```
var currentIndex = 0;
var urls = ['www.1.com.br','www.2.com.br', 'www.3.com.br'];
document.getElementById('someButton').addEventListener('click', function () {
    currentIndex = Math.min(currentIndex + 1, urls.length - 1);
    document.getElementById('someFrame').setAttribute('src', urls[currentIndex]);
});
```

Comment: Thank you! It works. I doubt using ajax I updated my question, I appreciate if you can help me again

Answer (score 1):

add to iframe `data-current-url="1"` and  `data-url1`, .... `data-urlN`
by pressing next just check current and if there is attribute:
 `data-url(current+1)` use value from that attribute and update `data-current-url="(current +1)"`

if there is no such atribute, so reset data-current-url to 1 and get url from `data-url1`. We will make loop by this solution